# Java/Swing - Apache Netbeans 11.2

Tags: java-swing, depuración, read

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano. Mi problema es el siguiente: Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en JAVA/SWING. Hasta el momento
todo va bien. Pero en el medio del desarrollo me he visto obligado a actualizar mi computadora. En un inicio mi entorno de desarrollo
era el siguiente:

```
* Windows 8.1 64 bits
* Java JDK Oracle 8
* JRE HotSpot 8
* Netbeans 8.2
* PostgreSQL 8
```

Ahora mi entorno es:

```
* Windows 10 64 bits
* AdoptOpenJDK 11 LTS
* JRE OpenJ9
* Apache Netbeans 11.2
* PostgreSQL 12
```

El problema es que después de actualizar, cuando intento iniciar el proceso de debugger este comienza a ejecutar paso a paso como lo hace siempre
pero cuando llega una clase o método de una clase compilada (por ejemplo DefaultModel, JList, etc) procede con el proceso de debugging dentro de
la misma. Esto antes no sucedía. Como puede evitar que esto pase. Ya que vuelve imposible poder terminar el proceso de debug, ya que queda atrapado
dentro de estas clases y métodos. Desde ya, gracias por su ayuda. A continuación les dejo una serie de capturas para describir el inconveniente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Siempre ha funcionado así, la diferencia posiblemente sea que está tratando de decompilar el código ya que algo me dice que no bajaste el zip del código.

Comment: Hola, mil gracias por responder. Pero antes no me sucedía eso. Cuando dices que no baje el zip del código. A que te refieres? Y porque antes no sucedía?.  Y por último como puedo evitar que decompile el código. Saludos

Comment: Hola nuevamente, después de pensar en la respuesta del amigo de México, he probado nuevamente a iniciar el debug y he encontrado la respuesta. Desde ya gracias nuevamente. Saludos a todos y te tengan un gran año.